# Conditional analysis in raster layer based on values in another layer

Tags: r

If I have a raster stack:

```
require(raster)
r_test <- stack(
  raster(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, vals = sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 100, TRUE)),
  raster(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, vals = rnorm(100, 7, 0.4)
```

And I want to apply a function to *layer.2* based on the value in the same cell in *layer.1*, how would I go about that?

As a simple example, multiplying the values in *layer.2* where the equivalent cell in *layer.1* equals -1.

Comment: Hum, perhaps `overlay` could be used for this? `overlay(x = r_test[[1]], y = r_test[[2]], fun = function(x, y) ifelse(x == -1, x * y, y))`

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik. That's where I ended up as well. It works, so write it up as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the `overlay()` function works quite well and in many contexts. Contradicting my first stab at this answer, in my experience, the `ifelse()` can be significantly either more or less efficient, especially for larger rasters.  For a raster of 1000 rows/cols simple raster algebra will be faster.  If I bump this to 10000 rows/cols then the `ifelse()` call is better.

```
library(raster)
r_test <- stack(
  raster(ncols = 1000, nrows = 1000, vals = sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 1000000, TRUE)),
  raster(ncols = 1000, nrows = 1000, vals = rnorm(1000000, 7, 0.4))
)

##  While overlay() works this is a more general solution and is
##      more efficient for large raster data sets:
system.time(
r_out <- r_test[[1]] * r_test[[2]] * (r_test[[1]] == -1) + r_test[[2]] * (r_test[[1]] != -1)
)
# N=1000x1000 cells:
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.05    0.01    0.06
# N=10000x10000 cells:
#   user  system elapsed 
#   48.36   19.60   77.56 

system.time(
r_out <- overlay(x = r_test[[1]], y = r_test[[2]], fun = function(x, y) ifelse(x == -1, x * y, y))
)
# N=1000x1000 cells:
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.53    0.08    0.64
# N=10000x10000 cells:
#   user  system elapsed 
#   19.77    5.82   26.53
```

Comment: Strange, no? Why would that be?

Comment: I'm guessing it could be very hardware and potentially data dependent behavior. But to note, I'm running the above code on a machine where memory is not limited in any significant way for the data presented, so I'd expect that not to be a huge issue. That said, without digging into nitty gritty details I couldn't really say.